# Ugly placement of exponent

Tags: math-mode, formatting, pdftex

Consider the next code

```
\[\frac{p(x_t^i, \theta^i)}{p(x_t^j, \theta^j)}\]
```

Which will display

[image]

As you see, the first exponent `j` is placed much higher then the second. I consider this quite ugly like this, especially since the `i`s align in the numerator. I've tried to align the `j`s by adding some empty space `\theta_{\ }^j)}` or using `\vphantom`

```
\[\frac{p(x_t^i, \theta^i)}{p(x_t^j, \theta\vphantom{_t}^j)}\]
```

, but nothing works: pdflatex seems to be stubborn.

Only if I put an actual symbol there will the exponents align

```
\[\frac{p(x_t^i, \theta^i)}{p(x_t^j, \theta_t^j)}\]
```

[image]

But I don't want that extra `t` there. How else can I align the `j` exponents in this equation?

Comment: TeX lowers exponents when in a cramped style; solution: `\theta_{\vphantom{t}}^{j}`

Comment: @egreg Ok, I was using \vphantom wrong... I typed `\theta\vphantom{_t}^j`, which didn't work. If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @egreg so `\vphantom{arg}` would place a vertical space with its typeset argument but without actually showing that argument in the typeset document?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh That’s precisely the idea.

Comment: You can also use `\theta_{\strut}^j`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX typesets a fraction in display style, it sets the numerator in text style and the denominator in *cramped* text style, which differs from the normal one in some small aspects, the most notable of which is the lowering of exponents.

However, in the denominator you have `x_{t}^{j}` where the exponent needs to be raised anyhow because of the subscript.

This is one of the cases where some dummy bits are needed in order to keep the symmetry between objects. Another case is

```
a_{i}x_{i}^n
```

where the subscripts wouldn't be aligned because of the missing superscript in the first atom. Here the solution would be to add an empty exponent or, even better, a phantom. A phantom is the solution also for your problem, see below.

These fine adjustments cannot be done automatically, because they depend on several factors. With some practice, you'll add them without even having to think, but an accurate final revision will reveal where something should be fixed to get perfect typesetting (which is still a craft, even with the aid of a computer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{p(x_{t}^{i}, \theta^{i})}{p(x_{t}^{j}, \theta_{\vphantom{t}}^{j})}
\]

\end{document}
```

Phantoms come in three varieties: `\vphantom` (only reserves the vertical space), `\hphantom` (only reserves the horizontal space) and `\phantom` (the combination of both the previous phantoms).

[image]